# UIIMagePickerController not working properly with Swift 3

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, swift3

I'm getting crazy with this.

While migrating a simple UIIMagePicker implementation I have everything working properly , no issues, no warning.
Running on both simulator and device the PickerController just don't take into consideration the new image and won't apply to the UImageView.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureImageView: UIImageView!
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    picker.delegate = self
    }

//Opening Camera to take a new picture
@IBAction func takeNewPictureButtonDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
    } else {
        noCamera()
    }
}

//Opening the library to select an existing picture
@IBAction func openPicturesLibraryButtonDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//MARK: - Delegates
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    var  chosenImage = UIImage()
    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
    profilePictureImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill //3
    profilePictureImageView.image = chosenImage //4
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) //5
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func noCamera(){
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(
        title: "No Camera",
        message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
        preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style:.default,
        handler: nil)
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    present(
        alertVC,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}   
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say: this is what the consolle is printing out:
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

Comment: Thanks Nirav D but that's not the case. My info.plist file already embeds Privacy - Camera Usage Description and Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Comment: Forcing me to check the consolle to print here the solution for further investigation, actually gave the solution :-)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/57026
 
 This was my imagePickerController: 

     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

 This is how it changes (`Any` rather than `AnyObject`):

     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

 hope this could help  someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

set delegate to self in viewdidload